Why is my transferred data being written into disk out-of-order after passing a certain number of asynchronous tasks running?
So I have those two scripts that are meant to be used for extremely fast file transfers in local networks
Receiver Script:
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
import time

import aiofiles
import lz4.frame

# Configuration
LISTEN_IP = '0.0.0.0'  # Listen on all interfaces
LISTEN_PORT = 5000  # Starting port, increment for each chunk
NUM_CONNECTIONS = int(sys.argv[1])  # Number of parallel connections (must match the sender)
OUTPUT_FILE_PATH = 'received_file'  # File to save the received data

# Setup logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()]
)

# Shared progress variables
total_bytes_received = 0
bytes_lock = asyncio.Lock()
chunk_received = [False] * NUM_CONNECTIONS


async def progress_reporter():
    """
    Periodically logs the total bytes received and the current transfer speed.
    """
    global total_bytes_received
    start_time = time.time()
    while not all(chunk_received):
        async with bytes_lock:
            bytes_so_far = total_bytes_received
        elapsed = time.time() - start_time
        speed = bytes_so_far / elapsed if elapsed > 0 else 0
        print(f"Received {bytes_so_far} bytes so far. Speed: {speed / (1024 * 1024):.2f} MB/s", end='\r')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)  # Update every second


async def receive_chunk(chunk_id, file_chunks):
    """
    Sets up a server to receive a specific chunk based on the chunk_id.
    """
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        lambda reader, writer: handle_client(reader, writer, chunk_id, file_chunks, server),
        LISTEN_IP, LISTEN_PORT + chunk_id)
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    logging.info(f"Listening for chunk {chunk_id} on {addr}")
    async with server:
        await server.start_serving()
        await server.wait_closed()


async def handle_client(reader, writer, chunk_id, file_chunks, server):
    """
    Handles the incoming connection for a specific chunk, receives the data,
    decompresses it, and stores it in the file_chunks list.
    """
    global total_bytes_received
    data = bytearray()
    logging.info(f"Connection established for chunk {chunk_id}")

    try:
        while True:
            chunk = await reader.read(2**20)  # Read in 1MB chunks
            if not chunk:
                break
            data += chunk
            # Update the total bytes received
            async with bytes_lock:
                total_bytes_received += len(chunk)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error receiving chunk {chunk_id}: {e}")

    try:
        # Ensure complete data is received before decompressing
        decompressed_data = lz4.frame.decompress(data)
        file_chunks[chunk_id] = decompressed_data
        logging.info(f"Chunk {chunk_id} decompressed successfully. Size: {len(decompressed_data)} bytes.")
        chunk_received[chunk_id] = True
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Unexpected error during decompression for chunk {chunk_id}: {e}")
        file_chunks[chunk_id] = b''

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    logging.info(f"Connection closed for chunk {chunk_id}")
    server.close()


async def main():
    """
    Main function to orchestrate the receiving of all chunks and reassembling the file.
    """
    start_time = time.time()

    file_chunks = [None] * NUM_CONNECTIONS  # Initialize list to hold each chunk's data
    tasks = []

    # Start the progress reporter
    reporter_task = asyncio.create_task(progress_reporter())

    # Start listening and receiving chunks
    for i in range(NUM_CONNECTIONS):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(receive_chunk(i, file_chunks)))

    # Wait for all chunks to be received and the completion signal
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    # Stop the reporter
    reporter_task.cancel()
    try:
        await reporter_task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass

    # Reassemble the file in the correct order
    async with aiofiles.open(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, 'wb') as f:
        for i, chunk_data in enumerate(file_chunks):
            if chunk_data:
                await f.write(chunk_data)
                logging.info(f"Chunk {i} written to output file.")
            else:
                logging.warning(f"Chunk {i} is empty or failed to decompress.")

    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    logging.info(f"File received in {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info("Receiver stopped by user.")

Sender Script:
import asyncio
import logging
import os
import sys
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import aiofiles
import lz4.frame

# Configuration
SERVER_IP = '127.0.0.1'  # Receiver IP (use the correct IP)
SERVER_PORT = 5000  # Starting port, increment for each chunk
NUM_CONNECTIONS = int(sys.argv[1])  # Number of parallel connections (adjust as necessary)
FILE_PATH = '1gb'  # File to be sent

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor for compression
compression_executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_CONNECTIONS)


async def send_chunk(chunk_data, chunk_id):
    """Send a chunk of data to the receiver asynchronously."""
    logging.info(f"Sending chunk {chunk_id}")
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT + chunk_id)
    writer.write(chunk_data)
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    logging.info(f"Chunk {chunk_id} sent")


def compress_chunk(chunk_data):
    """Compress a chunk of data using LZ4."""
    return lz4.frame.compress(chunk_data)


async def process_chunk(file, start, end, chunk_id):
    """Read, compress, and return a chunk of data."""
    logging.info(f"Reading chunk {chunk_id} from {start} to {end}")
    chunk_data = await file.read(end - start)
    logging.info(f"Chunk {chunk_id} read, with size file of {len(chunk_data)}")

    # Run the compression in a separate thread
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    logging.info(f"Compressing chunk {chunk_id}")
    compressed_data = await loop.run_in_executor(compression_executor, compress_chunk, chunk_data)
    logging.info(f"Chunk {chunk_id} compressed")
    return compressed_data


async def main():
    start_time = time.time()

    # Read and compress the file asynchronously
    file_size = os.path.getsize(FILE_PATH)
    chunk_size = file_size // NUM_CONNECTIONS

    tasks = []
    async with aiofiles.open(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as file:
        for i in range(NUM_CONNECTIONS):
            start = i * chunk_size
            end = start + chunk_size if i < NUM_CONNECTIONS - 1 else file_size

            # Create an asyncio task for reading and compressing each chunk
            tasks.append(process_chunk(file, start, end, i))

        # Wait for all chunks to be processed
        chunks = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        # Create tasks for sending each chunk
        send_tasks = [send_chunk(chunks[i], i) for i in range(NUM_CONNECTIONS)]
        await asyncio.gather(*send_tasks)

    end_time = time.time()
    logging.info(f"File sent in {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

When I run both scripts with 8 asynchronous tasks and then compare the md5 hashes of the received file and the original file they are the same and everything is perfect:
Receiver Script Logs With 8 Asynchronous Tasks:
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 0 on ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 1 on ('0.0.0.0', 5001)
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 2 on ('0.0.0.0', 5002)
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 3 on ('0.0.0.0', 5003)
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 4 on ('0.0.0.0', 5004)
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 5 on ('0.0.0.0', 5005)
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 6 on ('0.0.0.0', 5006)
2024-08-28 11:35:34,563 - INFO - Listening for chunk 7 on ('0.0.0.0', 5007)
2024-08-28 11:35:38,146 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:35:38,147 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:35:38,148 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:35:38,149 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:35:38,149 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:35:38,150 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:35:38,151 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:35:38,152 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:35:40,982 - INFO - Chunk 4 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,076 - INFO - Chunk 5 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,083 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:35:41,091 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:35:41,198 - INFO - Chunk 6 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,304 - INFO - Chunk 1 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,307 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:35:41,318 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:35:41,421 - INFO - Chunk 0 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,425 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:35:41,534 - INFO - Chunk 2 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,639 - INFO - Chunk 3 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,639 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:35:41,777 - INFO - Chunk 7 decompressed successfully. Size: 134217728 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:35:41,780 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:35:41,785 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:35:42,064 - INFO - Chunk 0 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:42,155 - INFO - Chunk 1 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:42,252 - INFO - Chunk 2 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:42,347 - INFO - Chunk 3 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:42,550 - INFO - Chunk 4 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:42,769 - INFO - Chunk 5 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:42,961 - INFO - Chunk 6 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:43,190 - INFO - Chunk 7 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:35:43,696 - INFO - File received in 9.14 seconds

Sender Script Logs With 8 Asynchronous Tasks:
2024-08-28 11:35:36,620 - INFO - Reading chunk 0 from 0 to 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:36,624 - INFO - Reading chunk 1 from 134217728 to 268435456
2024-08-28 11:35:36,629 - INFO - Reading chunk 2 from 268435456 to 402653184
2024-08-28 11:35:36,633 - INFO - Reading chunk 3 from 402653184 to 536870912
2024-08-28 11:35:36,637 - INFO - Reading chunk 4 from 536870912 to 671088640
2024-08-28 11:35:36,645 - INFO - Reading chunk 5 from 671088640 to 805306368
2024-08-28 11:35:36,657 - INFO - Reading chunk 6 from 805306368 to 939524096
2024-08-28 11:35:36,658 - INFO - Reading chunk 7 from 939524096 to 1073741824
2024-08-28 11:35:36,728 - INFO - Chunk 0 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:36,729 - INFO - Compressing chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:35:36,845 - INFO - Chunk 1 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:36,845 - INFO - Compressing chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:35:37,008 - INFO - Chunk 2 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:37,008 - INFO - Compressing chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:35:37,021 - INFO - Chunk 0 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:37,228 - INFO - Chunk 3 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:37,229 - INFO - Compressing chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:35:37,236 - INFO - Chunk 1 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:37,376 - INFO - Chunk 2 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:37,380 - INFO - Chunk 4 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:37,381 - INFO - Compressing chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:35:37,592 - INFO - Chunk 5 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:37,592 - INFO - Compressing chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:35:37,642 - INFO - Chunk 3 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:37,643 - INFO - Chunk 4 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:37,760 - INFO - Chunk 6 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:37,760 - INFO - Compressing chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:35:37,865 - INFO - Chunk 7 read, with size file of 134217728
2024-08-28 11:35:37,865 - INFO - Compressing chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:35:38,001 - INFO - Chunk 5 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:38,143 - INFO - Chunk 6 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:38,144 - INFO - Chunk 7 compressed
2024-08-28 11:35:38,145 - INFO - Sending chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:35:38,146 - INFO - Sending chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:35:38,147 - INFO - Sending chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:35:38,148 - INFO - Sending chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:35:38,149 - INFO - Sending chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:35:38,149 - INFO - Sending chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:35:38,150 - INFO - Sending chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:35:38,151 - INFO - Sending chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:35:40,645 - INFO - Chunk 5 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,649 - INFO - Chunk 1 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,658 - INFO - Chunk 2 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,660 - INFO - Chunk 3 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,673 - INFO - Chunk 6 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,685 - INFO - Chunk 4 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,693 - INFO - Chunk 0 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,693 - INFO - Chunk 7 sent
2024-08-28 11:35:40,694 - INFO - File sent in 4.07 seconds

MD5 hash comparison:
└─# md5sum received_file 1gb
286e80b3b7420263038ab06d76774043  received_file
286e80b3b7420263038ab06d76774043  1gb

However a VERY strange thing I experienced is whenever I make the asynchronous tasks number 9 or higher the md5 hashes of the received_file and the original file are being different.
Receiver Script Logs With 9 Asynchronous Tasks:
2024-08-28 11:37:56,229 - INFO - Listening for chunk 0 on ('0.0.0.0', 5000)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,230 - INFO - Listening for chunk 1 on ('0.0.0.0', 5001)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,230 - INFO - Listening for chunk 2 on ('0.0.0.0', 5002)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,230 - INFO - Listening for chunk 3 on ('0.0.0.0', 5003)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,230 - INFO - Listening for chunk 4 on ('0.0.0.0', 5004)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,230 - INFO - Listening for chunk 5 on ('0.0.0.0', 5005)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,230 - INFO - Listening for chunk 6 on ('0.0.0.0', 5006)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,230 - INFO - Listening for chunk 7 on ('0.0.0.0', 5007)
2024-08-28 11:37:56,231 - INFO - Listening for chunk 8 on ('0.0.0.0', 5008)
2024-08-28 11:38:00,567 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:38:00,567 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:38:00,567 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:38:00,568 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:38:00,568 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:38:00,576 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:38:00,579 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:38:00,579 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:38:00,579 - INFO - Connection established for chunk 8
2024-08-28 11:38:02,911 - INFO - Chunk 2 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:02,914 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:38:03,068 - INFO - Chunk 3 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,071 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:38:03,162 - INFO - Chunk 8 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304648 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,165 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 8
2024-08-28 11:38:03,289 - INFO - Chunk 4 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,292 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:38:03,385 - INFO - Chunk 1 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,464 - INFO - Chunk 0 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,465 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:38:03,471 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:38:03,562 - INFO - Chunk 5 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,641 - INFO - Chunk 7 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,642 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:38:03,648 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:38:03,735 - INFO - Chunk 6 decompressed successfully. Size: 119304647 bytes.
2024-08-28 11:38:03,735 - INFO - Connection closed for chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:38:04,006 - INFO - Chunk 0 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,086 - INFO - Chunk 1 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,163 - INFO - Chunk 2 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,236 - INFO - Chunk 3 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,319 - INFO - Chunk 4 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,424 - INFO - Chunk 5 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,504 - INFO - Chunk 6 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,602 - INFO - Chunk 7 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:04,696 - INFO - Chunk 8 written to output file.
2024-08-28 11:38:06,516 - INFO - File received in 10.29 seconds

Sender Script Logs With 9 Asynchronous Tasks:
2024-08-28 11:37:59,327 - INFO - Reading chunk 0 from 0 to 119304647
2024-08-28 11:37:59,327 - INFO - Reading chunk 1 from 119304647 to 238609294
2024-08-28 11:37:59,332 - INFO - Reading chunk 2 from 238609294 to 357913941
2024-08-28 11:37:59,337 - INFO - Reading chunk 3 from 357913941 to 477218588
2024-08-28 11:37:59,343 - INFO - Reading chunk 4 from 477218588 to 596523235
2024-08-28 11:37:59,345 - INFO - Reading chunk 5 from 596523235 to 715827882
2024-08-28 11:37:59,353 - INFO - Reading chunk 6 from 715827882 to 835132529
2024-08-28 11:37:59,353 - INFO - Reading chunk 7 from 835132529 to 954437176
2024-08-28 11:37:59,354 - INFO - Reading chunk 8 from 954437176 to 1073741824
2024-08-28 11:37:59,399 - INFO - Chunk 0 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:37:59,401 - INFO - Compressing chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:37:59,473 - INFO - Chunk 1 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:37:59,473 - INFO - Compressing chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:37:59,589 - INFO - Chunk 2 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:37:59,589 - INFO - Compressing chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:37:59,727 - INFO - Chunk 0 compressed
2024-08-28 11:37:59,729 - INFO - Chunk 1 compressed
2024-08-28 11:37:59,774 - INFO - Chunk 3 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:37:59,774 - INFO - Compressing chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:37:59,774 - INFO - Chunk 2 compressed
2024-08-28 11:37:59,884 - INFO - Chunk 4 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:37:59,885 - INFO - Compressing chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:37:59,964 - INFO - Chunk 5 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:37:59,965 - INFO - Compressing chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:38:00,104 - INFO - Chunk 6 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:38:00,105 - INFO - Compressing chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:38:00,107 - INFO - Chunk 3 compressed
2024-08-28 11:38:00,307 - INFO - Chunk 4 compressed
2024-08-28 11:38:00,311 - INFO - Chunk 5 compressed
2024-08-28 11:38:00,312 - INFO - Chunk 7 read, with size file of 119304647
2024-08-28 11:38:00,312 - INFO - Compressing chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:38:00,313 - INFO - Chunk 6 compressed
2024-08-28 11:38:00,384 - INFO - Chunk 8 read, with size file of 119304648
2024-08-28 11:38:00,388 - INFO - Compressing chunk 8
2024-08-28 11:38:00,499 - INFO - Chunk 7 compressed
2024-08-28 11:38:00,565 - INFO - Chunk 8 compressed
2024-08-28 11:38:00,566 - INFO - Sending chunk 0
2024-08-28 11:38:00,566 - INFO - Sending chunk 1
2024-08-28 11:38:00,566 - INFO - Sending chunk 2
2024-08-28 11:38:00,567 - INFO - Sending chunk 3
2024-08-28 11:38:00,567 - INFO - Sending chunk 4
2024-08-28 11:38:00,567 - INFO - Sending chunk 5
2024-08-28 11:38:00,569 - INFO - Sending chunk 6
2024-08-28 11:38:00,570 - INFO - Sending chunk 7
2024-08-28 11:38:00,571 - INFO - Sending chunk 8
2024-08-28 11:38:02,691 - INFO - Chunk 2 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,709 - INFO - Chunk 3 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,721 - INFO - Chunk 8 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,788 - INFO - Chunk 4 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,924 - INFO - Chunk 1 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,932 - INFO - Chunk 0 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,932 - INFO - Chunk 5 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,941 - INFO - Chunk 7 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,942 - INFO - Chunk 6 sent
2024-08-28 11:38:02,945 - INFO - File sent in 3.62 seconds

MD5 hash comparisons:
└─# md5sum received_file 1gb
9b83cf2fa088c8b2ceb8527d8e9d9da8  received_file
286e80b3b7420263038ab06d76774043  1gb

And before you say it is probably data loss, no it is not because the file sizes of the received_file and the original file are the EXACT same:
└─# ls -la received_file 1gb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1073741824 Aug 27 22:50 1gb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1073741824 Aug 28 11:39 received_file

So that is why I suspect the data being written to the received_file out-of-order when it is 9 tasks for some reason I am unaware of.
Why is this happening specifically with 9 tasks and above? And how can I potentially fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Not an expert on async and multithreading, but some thoughts on troubleshooting:


One thing I notice is that in your 8-task case, your test case seems a little too perfect. 1GB (i.e., 1024^3 bytes) divides evenly into 8 chunks. What happens with 7 or 16 chunks, or if your file isn't exactly divisible into 8 chunks?


Can you check for out of order blocks? Rather than checking 362,880 different permutations (i.e., 9!), figure out which block is first in the reconstruction, then the second one, etc.,



When I first started using the scripts I was just using random numbers as task numbers, when I noticed that some are matching the MD5 hash and some are not I started from 1 task till 8 tasks to pinpoint at which task number does the problem start and it is indeed 9 and after, so I do not think it has anything to do with 1gb being divisible into 8. Because when I try 16 it is giving me a different hash than the original file, and when I try 7 even tho it is not divisible it is giving the same hash for both files

hello LuckyCoder, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please make your example a little more "minimal"? see: minimal-reproducible-example. It will make helping you easier and make your question much more helpful to people with a similar issue. Have a wonderful day! :)

it is as minimal as possible, in the code I provided it only has the compression and the data transfer functionalities which are required to reproduce the bug I am encountering

Does the issue still happens if you disable the asynchronicity? Sometimes, it has nothing to do with asynch.

I guess in the sender, the process_chunk was done out of order. It might help if you perform a seek before reading.

There is nothing wrong in the sender, I just ran more tests to verify the chunks' hashes between transfer, each chunk had the same hash as the original sent chunk, after being decompressed i checked each chunks' hashes AGAIN and compared them with the original chunks' before being compressed and they were correct. So the hashes upon transferring the data is correct, the hashes upon decompressing the data is correct but the hashes upon writing the data into disk is wrong for some fucking reason i cannot understand. also wrote a simple python script that compares bytes of two files and -->

pinpoints their differences, it is not always the same number but it seems like after the 160000th byte the changes start happening, data starts to be different and everything but all the bytes still have the same length and size but different values. So the problem has to do with the last snippet of the code where I write the chunks into disk but I still haven't figured out the bug

You don't show how you are verifying hashes on each chunk. It seems to me you are creating NUM_CONNECTIONS tasks and because you are not seeking to the start location, the code can only work if the tasks are executed in task creation order and you have no control over that. It would be prudent to do the seek and read together in a critical section (under control of a lock). And you gain nothing by using asyncio for reading the file since you are not sending until all chunks have been read in anyway. Also, doing compression (a CPU-bound task) in a thread pool buys you nothing.

@HaiVu Yes, a seek followed by a read is recommended. But the two calls must be done without interruption, i.e. under control of a lock, Based on the log, it does not appear that the reads were done out of order.
